# Convert to Swift 3 - Notification Centre dispatch queue

Tags: ios, swift2, swift3

Struggling to convert this to Swift 3. Can you help?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
    self.delegate.locationDidUpdateToLocation(self.currentLocation!)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(kLocationDidChangeNotification, object: self, userInfo: userInfo as [NSObject : AnyObject])
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what that delegate method is, but the rest of it would look like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notification_name, object: self, userInfo:userInfo )

}
```

I'm not sure about `kLocationDidChangeNotification`

Comment: It works! Must confess quite confused about all the changes on notification center, there are so many versions out there and none seems right!